# Get the element of a list in Dataframe based on column values in Pandas

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

I want to select one specific element of a column of lists based on another columns cell value in a Pandas Dataframe.

```
    list_column    value
0   [a, b, c]      0
1   [a, b, c]      2
2   [a, b, c]      1
```

so the desired output will be:

```
    list_column     value   selected
0   [a, b, c]       0       a
1   [a, b, c]       2       c
2   [a, b, c]       1       b
```

I tried using the
`df["selected"] = df['list'].str[df["value"]]` but was not managing to apply this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the previous solution doesn't work I've tested this one it works

```
mask = df[df['list_column'].map(len) > 0]  
for index in mask.index:  
    value = df.loc[index,'values']  
    df.loc[index,"selected"] = df.loc[index,'list_column'][value]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. The code was working so far but now I applied it to a larger database and it seems that it is facing some issues. I get the "KeyError: 0". Could it be that I have problems because the length of the list in the list_column is varying?

Comment: I've make a change, you have some empty lists that's why you got this error, I've fixed it to skip those values

Comment: Nevermind. It works fine, it was just a matter of reseting the index. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

For a vectorial approch use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) slicing:

```
import numpy as np

df['selected'] = np.vstack(df['list_column'])[np.arange(len(df)), df['value']]
```

Output:

```
  list_column  value selected
0   [a, b, c]      0        a
1   [a, b, c]      2        c
2   [a, b, c]      1        b
```